# Dynamic viscosity of gas mixture (appropriate estimation)

Tags: gas-laws, mixtures, adsorption, viscosity, separation-techniques

What estimation of the dynamic viscosity $\eta = f(T)$ $([\eta] = \pu{Pa·s})$ of the gas mixture components would you recommend during adsorption at a low temperature, approx. $\pu{293 K}$ to $\pu{333 K},$ and a relatively low pressure?

Gas mixture contains $\ce{N2}$ (the major component), $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ in the form of water vapor.

I assume the gas mixture to be ideal.

About a year ago, I use to calculate the dynamic viscosity using *Lennard–Jones coefficients* for a slightly different conditions if I recall correctly. However, I cannot find my calculations, hence I wanted to check whether using these coefficients would be relevant for such case.

Comment: What is "gas separation" ?

Comment: @Karl I referred to adsorption - corrected.

Comment: Ah, OK. Still: I could make a lot of assumptions about the process you have in your mind, and then the question would make sense. But I'd rather *you* told us.

Comment: See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 1 for mixing rules to get viscosity.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks, I think I got it by combining either Sutherland Equation with Herning-Zipperer Eq. or probably more precise Chapman-Enskog theory with Herning-Zipperer Eq. If I can ask you one more question... I can apply the Chapman-Enskog theory to obtain values of gas components/mixture conductivity $\lambda_k$ and binary diffusion $D_{AB}$. What would you recommend to use for molecular diffusion $D_m$, between two gases, which I need to obtain axial dispersion coefficient $D_{ax}$, which lumps all the negative effects on separation, thanks. (I'd neglect $H_2O$ in the first attempt.)

Comment: I believe that is also covered in Bird, et al, in a later chapter.

Comment: @ChetMiller Found it in the chapter 17 :), thanks.